# Change property of img through CSS class in outer div container

Tags: css, typo3

I want to change properties of an image via css. As I am doing this through typo3 I only have access to the outer div container (custom border of the content element).
So I added the following line to my css file:

```
.Bild-Startseite img { width:50%; }
```

The div container is using `Bild-Startseite`. Unfortunately this does not change the width of the image inside the div container...
What is going wrong?

The css file is here: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/klingler_ag/fileadmin/templates/css/screen/screen-PAGE-layout.css

And the site with the div container: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/klingler_ag/home.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a more specific selector is already targeting the `<img>` :

```
#main img, 
#main audio, 
#main video, 
#main embed {
height: auto;
width: auto;
max-width: 100%;
/* ID's will always take precedence over classes */
}
```

You can try adding an [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) rule at the end of the declaration .. or add it as an inline-style

```
.Bild-Startseite img {
 width: 50% !important; 
 }
```

Comment: Works! But now the image is 50% of the div container and the div container is still the original image size... This is not what I wanted... :-(

Comment: Well what exactly did you want?

Comment: That the img is 50% of the window width without blank space to the right of the image...

Comment: Adding `margin: 0 auto;` will at least center it, though I will try to find a real solution, give me a moment ..

Comment: @reto What do you mean by blank space to the right ? As far as I can tell, there's no blank space on the right side. Do you pretend to have it aligned with what ?

Comment: @Reto So, after you scale down your image to 50% you want it to be align right is that it?

Comment: Yes, is this just an aligment issue?

Comment: @Reto and you also want to text to follow? Or just want the image to the right, by preserving the container width? If it's the last, try to `float:right;` your image.

Comment: @Reto So, comment out your rules on `.Bild-Startseite img` and instead do: `figure.csc-textpic-image.csc-textpic-last { float: right; width: 400px;}` play with the `width` property to fit your needs, and let me know if that worked.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that easy. I only want to change this image and not all others on the site. As the code is generated by typo3, I can only set a css property for the outer container.

Comment: @Reto If you can set a css property for the outer container, **specifically to that page**, then you should be good to go. Use the `child selector` `>` to make sure you just target that image when that `class` is present. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Sounds good. But unfortunately I am not a css expert. Can you show me how this would look in code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255119/change-size-of-image-through-css-in-outer-div-container

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29040/discussion-between-mem-and-reto)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways could be solution.

1.

```
.Bild-Startseite img { width: 50% !important; }
```

2.

```
#main img,
#main audio,
#main video,
#main embed {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

in screen-PAGE-layout.css, remove width attribute.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working; there are only some other css rules with higher specificity.

Use:

```
.Bild-Startseite img { width: 50% !important; }
```

to overwrite all other `width` applied to this element.