# Change size of image through css in outer div container

Tags: css, typo3

I want to change the width of an image via css. As I am doing this through typo3 I only have access to the outer div container (custom border of the content element).
So I added the following line to my css file:

```
.Bild-Startseite img { max-width:50% !important; }
```

The div container is using `Bild-Startseite`. Unfortunately the container does not resize, leaving a blank area on the right of the image. How can this be corrected, so the image is aligned to the right and the text floating around it?
I only want to change this image and not the others on the site. Also typo3 does not give me access to the other containers.

The site is here: http://web182.theta.ibone.ch/klingler_ag/home.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order for that to work, you should style your image container. In your case:

```
figure.csc-textpic-image.csc-textpic-last
```

You stated that you wish this to be applied only on this specific page.
Please try the following:

```
#c48 figure.csc-textpic-image.csc-textpic-last {
    max-width: 400px; /* or whatever value you may fit. */
}
```

I believe `#c48` is specific to that page only. So you have that rule applied only to that page.

If `#c48` is not specific to that page only, then you should add a css class to your body page.

You should edit your `typo3 template` from the `setup field` on your `main template`, and do:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    ...

    bodyTagCObject {
        field = uid
        wrap = <body class="uid-|">
    }

    ...
}
```

With this you would have a single class and, with that, you can simple do:

```
.uid-yourIdNumberHere figure.csc-textpic-image.csc-textpic-last {

//your page specific style here.

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. The size of the image does not change. What works (partially) is `#c48 div > div { max-width: 50%; }`. However the text does no longer float below the picture... :-( Why is that?